# jssor size adjustor without maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: jssor

Since one of our organization's client asked us to change the slide show  height slightly not width (reason on maintaining aspect ratio in small screen device the slider gets very small).

I know about this jssor function `$ScaleWidth(width)`; but only have to adjust height.

So created the following function to resize based on the scale value of transform css property of jssor instantiated object's tag id, which is passed as parameter for the following function.

```
function jssorResolutionAdjustor(id)
    {
        setTimeout(function() {

            var idObj = $('#' + id);
            var immediateChild = idObj.children('div');
            var transformMatrix = '';
            var transformMatrixValues = '';
            var transformCss = '';
            transformMatrix = immediateChild.css('transform');

            transformMatrixValues = transformMatrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);

            var scaleXValue = transformMatrixValues[0];
            var scaleXValueFixed = parseFloat(scaleXValue).toFixed(2);
            var scaleYValue = (scaleXValue * 1.2).toFixed(2);

            if (scaleXValueFixed >= 0.75)
            {
                scaleYValue = 1;
            }

            if ('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style)
            {
                transformCss = {'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')',
                    'transform': ''};
            }
            else if ('MozTransform' in document.body.style)
            {
                transformCss = {'-moz-transform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')'};
            }
            else if ('transform' in document.body.style)
            {
                transformCss = {'tansform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')'};
            }

            $(immediateChild).css(transformCss);

        }, 0);
    }
```

It worked flawlessly in desktop browser (firefox, chrome only I checked) but if opened on mobile phone (iphone, android) means it scaled to too big size. Also I checked the value in mobile and in desktop by adjusting browser screen size to phone screen size same value is returned in `alert('scaleXValue=' + scaleXValue + '<-->' + 'scaleXValueFixed=' + scaleXValueFixed + '<-->' + 'scaleYValue=' + scaleYValue);`.

I can't get any clue so here I attach the screen shot of failed solution in mobile.

[image: Screen shot from iphone]

And I call this function on loading and resizing the window.

```
jssorResolutionAdjustor('jssor_image_gallery');
$(window).resize(function() {
    jssorResolutionAdjustor('jssor_image_gallery');
});
```

`jssor_image_gallery` is the id given in jssor instance

`jssor_slider_image = new $JssorSlider$('jssor_image_gallery', options);`

**Updated (1):**

Here is my jssor function

```
function imageJssor()
{
    var _CaptionTransitions = [];
    _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] = {$Duration: 600, $Clip: 8, $Move: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutExpo};

    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: false,
        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2,
            $Cols: 6,
            $Align: 260,
            $SpacingX: 3, //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 6                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        },
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2
        },
        $CaptionSliderOptions: {//[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$, //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
            $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions, //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
            $PlayInMode: 0, //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            $PlayOutMode: 0                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
        }
    };
    jssor_slider_image = new $JssorSlider$('jssor_image_gallery', options);

    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        /*  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

         if (windowWidth) {
         var windowHeight = $(window).height();
         var originalWidth = jssor_slider_image.$OriginalWidth();
         var originalHeight = jssor_slider_image.$OriginalHeight();

         var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
         if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
         scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
         alert(scaleWidth);
         }

         jssor_slider_image.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
         }
         else
         window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);

         var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
         alert(bodyWidth);
         if (bodyWidth)
         jssor_slider_image.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth-150, 1920));
         else
         window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);        */

        var parentWidth = jssor_slider_image.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        //alert(parentWidth);
        if (parentWidth)
            jssor_slider_image.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 720));
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }

    ScaleSlider();

    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end
}


imageJssor();

$(document).on('click', '#one li', function() {
    var imageStartFrom = $(this).index();

    $('#image_gallery').hide();
    $('#jssor_image_gallery').show();

    jssor_slider_image.$PlayTo(imageStartFrom);
    jssor_slider_image.$Pause();

    jssorResolutionAdjustor('jssor_image_gallery');
    $(window).resize(function() {
        jssorResolutionAdjustor('jssor_image_gallery');
    });
});
```

**Updated (2):**

[image: Images of mobile and web with scale value]

Here in both images (web & mobile) the default scale ratio and my calculated values or looking same but as shown below image its working properly in website in desktop browser but not in mobile. Here I attached that image too for reference.
[image: Image of improper scaled image]

Here in the above image on left side the deer image get scaled to high with compare to right side image which is took from desktop browser.

**Updated (3):**
[image: parent_width_mobile_vs_web]
Please see below image's alert to verify the parentWidth both represents the same value only
[image: dom structure]

Also I attach my html dom structure with id which is used in jssor is highlighted in blue background.

Comment: I saw you scale slider base on parentWidth. Is parentWidth correctd as expected?

Comment: yes it is working properly in desktop environment but in mobile only I get the issue.

Comment: Please double check the parentWidth on mobile device then.

Comment: ok I will check the parentWidth on mobile device. But it is working in ipad and galaxy tab. So if screen is pocket friendly means issue arises. For that I will check parentWidth in desktop, tablet and mobile then update you.

Comment: Hi @jssor Thnks for you patience and eager reply. I updated the post with the required scale value. Please review it tell the solution to scale only height wise.

Comment: I haven't realize what's the exact problem of your slider. I just guess it doesn't fit width on some mobile devices, right?

Comment: OK, the parentWidth is the same (320) then. Please double check the screen width then. That's to say, in this page (picture at left side), the screen width is less than 320.

Comment: no in all mobile devices it won't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that if `-webkit-transform` was set means instead emptying the `transform` css property have to check browser (gecko, webkit, etc) engine also have `transform`. If it exist the priority will goes to `transform` while rendering the dom compared to `-webkit-transform`.

**FROM:**

```
if ('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style)
            {
                transformCss = {'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')',
                    'transform': ''};
        }
```

**TO:**

```
if ('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style)
            {

                transformCss = {'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')'};

                if ('transform' in document.body.style)
                {
                   transformCss = {'tansform': 'scale(' + scaleXValue + ',' + scaleYValue + ')'};
                }
            }
```